# Библиотека для word под Андроид

Tags: java, android

Есть ли какя нибудь удобная и простая библиотека для android. Чтобы можно было в ней создать word документ, и добавить допустим картинку и можно было указать как в Worde отступы рамки, короче все как в Worde?

Если бы можно было то хотелось бы и под Excel тоже такое использовать.

Буду благодарен